# Determine if $\{\int_0^1 f^2 ~\mathrm{d}x = 0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have to verify whether $S$ is a subspace of $V$:

$V = \mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R})$, that is, the set containing all continuous functions
and $S = \{f \in \mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R}): \int_0^1f(x)^2dx=0\}$

What I've got so far:

1. $\vdash 0 \in S$

   $f(x)=0 \implies \int_0^1f(x)^2dx = 0 \implies f \in S$
2. $\vdash h(x) = f(x) + g(x) \in S$

   $\int_0^1h(x)^2dx = \int_0^1f(x)^2dx + 2\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx + \int_0^1g(x)^2dx$

   $f(x), g(x) \in S \implies \int_0^1f(x)^2dx = \int_0^1g(x)^2dx = 0$

   $\int_0^1h(x)^2dx =  2\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$

I have the feeling that this last integral does not necessarily equals to $0$. However, to show that $S$ is not a subspace I need a counter example, and I couldn't come up with one so far...

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you say more clearly what $S$ is? I think you may have left out some information.

Comment: @AOrtiz : it is already defined at the 2nd line

Comment: Sorry! The integral must be zero. I edited the question.

Comment: Is there any nontrivial function in this set $S$?

Comment: Are your functions real-valued or can be complex-valued?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f$ is continuous, then $f^{2}$ is continuous. So, since $f^{2}\geq 0$, the condition $\int_{0}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx=0\implies f^{2}$ is identically $0$ on $[0,1]$. Hence, $f$ is identically $0$ on $[0,1]$. Therefore,

$$
S=\{f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):f(x)=0\quad\forall x\in[0,1]\}
.
$$

Comment: We have essentially the same answer, but I would point out that $S$ contains more than just the zero function.

Comment: Yes. Good point. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is continuous then $\int_0^1 f(x)^2 \, dx = 0$ if and only if $f$ vanishes on $[0,1]$. Thus you can write $$S = \{f \in {\cal C}(\mathbb{R}) : f(x) = 0 \quad \forall\, 0 \le x \le 1\}.$$

It is easy to check this set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Third possibility:

use the fact that $ |fg|\leq\frac{1}{2}(f^2+g^2)$. Therefore $\int |fg|\leq 0$, hence conclude  $\int fg= 0$. Then you can insert this in your proof.